# перенос определённого элемента в другой список из числа находящегося в списке

Tags: python

имеется список iteration_func в котором находится строка являющиеся числом в двоичной системе исчисления ( '00001000' )
как перенести все единицы из этого числа в другой список ?

```
num1, num2 = (int(x)for x in input().split())

iteration = input()
iteration_func = 0


if iteration == "+":
    iteration_func = num1 + num2
elif iteration == "-":
    iteration_func = num1 - num2
elif iteration == "*":
    iteration_func = num1 * num2
elif iteration == "/":
    iteration_func = num1 // num2

print(iteration_func)

iteration_func = bin(iteration_func)[2:].zfill(8)
iteration_func = [iteration_func]

print(*iteration_func)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если не проверять корректно ли ввел пользователь строку (т.е. что она содержит только 0 или 1), то код можно сделать таким:

```
num1 = input("enter bits #1: ")
num2 = input("enter bits #2: ")

pos = 0

res = ""

while pos < len(num1) and pos < len(num2):
    res += str(int(num1[len(num1) - pos - 1]) or int(num2[len(num2) - pos - 1]))
    pos += 1

res = res[::-1]

print(res)
```

или так:

```
num1 = input("enter bits #1: ")
num2 = input("enter bits #2: ")

num1 = '0' * (max(len(num1), len(num2)) - len(num1)) + num1
num2 = '0' * (max(len(num1), len(num2)) - len(num2)) + num2

res = ''
for i, j in zip(num1, num2):
    res += str(int(i) or int(j))

print(res)
```

или так:

```
num1 = input("enter bits #1: ")
num2 = input("enter bits #2: ")

num1 = '0' * (max(len(num1), len(num2)) - len(num1)) + num1
num2 = '0' * (max(len(num1), len(num2)) - len(num2)) + num2

res = ''.join(map(lambda obj: str(int(obj[0]) or int(obj[1])), zip(num1, num2)))

print(res)
```

или так:

```
import numpy

num1 = int(input("enter bits #1: "), 2)
num2 = int(input("enter bits #2: "), 2)

res = numpy.base_repr(num1 | num2, 2)

print(res)
```

или так:

```
num1 = int(input("enter bits #1: "), 2)
num2 = int(input("enter bits #2: "), 2)

res = str(bin(num1 | num2))[2::]

print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
num1, num2 = (int(x)for x in input().split())

iteration = input()
iteration_func = 0


if iteration == "+":
    iteration_func = num1 + num2
elif iteration == "-":
    iteration_func = num1 - num2
elif iteration == "*":
    iteration_func = num1 * num2
elif iteration == "/":
    iteration_func = num1 // num2

# if iteration_func < 0:
#    iteration_func *= -1


iteration_func = bin(iteration_func)[2:].zfill(8)
iteration_func = list(str(iteration_func))

res_list = []

for x in iteration_func:
    if x == "1":
        res_list.append(x)

print(res_list)
# print(len(res_list))
```

всем спасибо за помощь и участие :)